# Python pipeline error when deploying to EC2 setuptools_rust

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket

Hello I'm having this problem when trying to deploy a django application to aws, the app runs perfectly locally but when trying to deploy to aws this error shows up.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXO3s.png)

I tried to install that manually, but it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the docker version for your deployment runner is 20.x - it's probably this https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8105

Try pinning the deploy docker version to 19.03.13ce-1

Comment: Thank you, I found the solution in link :D!

Comment: @Alex - accept the answer if it helped you solve the problem